# Soap request signed by certificate. WS-Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client, wsdl2java, cxf-client

I received the WSDL which contains the security policy, as for now, judging by the wsdl i found out that it means that i need it to sign with certificate. No token server should be used.

**What i did:**
I used cxf wsdl2java to create java classes from the wsdl file. As far i saw CXF handles pretty well all the signing automatically so i added on java side STSClient with ws-security.signature.crypto and ws-security.encryption.crypto on the Client. Which basically does nothing and my Soap request contains only the body without any signing data. As a result nothing happens and no errors are printed out, which makes it really hard to solve my problem.

**Question:** 
How to sign the soap request without token server without any username/password?
Also address is http in the provided wsdl, should i override it to https?

**Received wsdl Policy snippet:**

```
 <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
              xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
              wsu:Id="SigOnly">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:InitiatorToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:X509Token
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:InitiatorToken>
            <sp:RecipientToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:X509Token
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:RecipientToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss10>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
```

**Received message header example:**

```
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                   soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-****">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-***">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>value=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          signatureValue==
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-***">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-***">
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>issuer name
                </ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>nmber</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
```

**My java snippet:**

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(generatedService);

    Init.init();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", keystorePassword);
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", signedCertificateAliasInTheKeystore);
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", new ClassPathResource(keyStore).getPath());
    properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password", keystorePassword);

    Merlin crypto = null;
    try {
      crypto = (Merlin) CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties);
    }
    catch (WSSecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();//temp
    }

    STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(((EndpointImpl) client.getEndpoint()).getBus());
    Map<String, Object> stsClientProperties = new HashMap<>();
    stsClient.setWsdlLocation(new ClassPathResource("MyWsdl.wsdl").getPath());
    stsClientProperties.put("ws-security.signature.crypto", crypto);
    stsClientProperties.put("ws-security.encryption.crypto", crypto);
    stsClient.setProperties(stsClientProperties);

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) generatedService;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.sts.client", stsClient);
    generatedService.callToTheOuterWorld(data);
```

**Second try which is basically copy of 
[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/WS-Security):**

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(generatedService);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "keystoreAlias");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS,
        ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName()); //callback has keystore password
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, new ClassPathResource("client_sign.properties").getPath());
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
generatedService.callToTheOuterWorld(data)
```

which throws : Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: EncryptionCrypto instantiation failed
If i remove the WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT i get no exception but header is still missing in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. 
Basically i found on SO example how to print out my request data and i used it to see my requests as a result it was overriding the headers to null :) Take a note on "getHeaders()" method.

```
Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
andlerChain.add(new SOAPLoggingHandler());
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

```
  class SOAPLoggingHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
      return null;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
      logToSystemOut(smc);
      return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
      logToSystemOut(smc);
      return true;
    }

    public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
    }

    private void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
      Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
              smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

      if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        System.out.println("\nOutbound message:");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("\nInbound message:");
      }

      SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
      try {
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in handler: " + e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if you don't have security policy in the wsdl but you need to add BinarySecurityToken, Signature and Digest? I also created client with wsdl2java from cxf 3.4 and I need to add headers

Comment: Hi @AlejandroL.Did you find the solution ?